# Independence of pairing axiom from $\mathsf{Z}$

Tags: set-theory

> Is Zermelo's axiom system, $\mathsf{Z}$ (which is, $\mathsf{ZF}-\text{replacement}$), consistent with $\neg \text{pairing}$?

I know that $(\mathsf{ZF}-\text{pairing})\vdash \text{pairing}$, by replacing $\mathcal{P(P(\emptyset))}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ with any given two sets $a,b$, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396713/why-is-the-axiom-of-pairing-required?noredirect=1&lq=1). But is it easy to find a model of $(\mathsf{Z}-\text{pairing})+\neg\text{pairing}$, assuming $\mathsf{Z}$ is consistant?

**Edit:** For clarification, I assume $\mathsf{Z}$ includes the following axioms:

1. Extensionality
2. Foundation
3. Unordered Pair
4. Empty Set
5. Infinity
6. Union
7. Power Set
8. Separation

Comment: Which axioms do you have in your Z? This is one of the reasons people will often include redundant axioms in ZF, since it's easier to talk about subtheories this way.

Comment: The axioms of $\mathsf{Z}$ are the same as defined in your notes:  (0) Extensionality
• (1) Foundation
• (2) Unordered Pair
• (3) Empty Set
• (4) Infinity
• (5) Union
• (6) Power Set
• (7) Separation

Comment: I mean, sure, but my notes don't include 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}[1]{\operatorname{cl}(#1)}$

One possible construction (I believe it is by Andreas):

A set $X$ is called "avoidable" if it satisfy the weak pairing property: $∀x,y\in X\exists z\in X\;(\{x,y\}⊆z)$

Start with $N=V_{ω+ω}$, and an avoidable $X\in N$,

Define $N_X=\{a\in N\mid X\nsubseteq \cl{a}\}$, you can verify that $N_X$ is a model of $Z$ minus infinity (the only tricky part is pairing), moreover, if $X\nsubseteq ω$ then it is a model of $Z$.

Now take two different elements, $a,b∈N$ such that $|a|,|b|>2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(a)=\operatorname{rank}(b)>ω$.

Now we need to make $a,b$ into avoidable sets, define $\overline a$ to be the closure of $\{a\}$ under pairing, and similarly for $\{b\}$.

From that we can get the structure $N_{\overline a}∪N_{\overline b}$ of Z-pairing+¬pairing

Again the only tricky part is to show it doesn't satisfy pairing.

> clearly $\overline a,\{\overline a,\overline b\}\notin N_{\overline a}$ and $\overline b,\{\overline a,\overline b\}\notin N_{\overline b}$.

> Assume $\overline b\notin N_{\overline a}$, in particular $b∈\cl{\overline a}$, because $|b|>2$ this implies $b=a$ (which we assumed it is not), or $b\in \operatorname{cl}(a)$ (which is impossible as they have the same rank), so $\overline b\in N_{\overline a}$, symmetric argument will show that $\overline a\in N_{\overline b}$, so $\overline a,\overline b\in N_{\overline a}∪N_{\overline b}∌\{\overline a,\overline b\}$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where to find any references for this (or similar) construction in the literature?

Comment: [Here is a paper from Andreas](https://www.uni-muenster.de/IVV5WS/WebHop/user/alietz/notes/zermelo.pdf) about similar points (although Andreas doesn't use this construction to show that Z-pairing+¬pairing is consistent). Note that in this mention Andreas defines the models $N_X$ as proper classes, inwhere I took some "ground model" $V_{ω+ω}$, the advantage of my construction is that you get a model, and not a class model. The advantage of Andreas construction is that you don't need the full power of ZF in the universe (which I used when I assumed $V_{ω+ω}$ exists), only Z