# What makes Tarski Grothendieck set theory non-empty?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, quantifiers

I'm fighting with [Grothendieck set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) for some time now. This is the framework for the automated proof checking system of [Mizar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_system) and hence there is a formalized version of the axioms [here](http://markun.cs.shinshu-u.ac.jp/mirror/mizar/JFM/Axiomatics/tarski.abs.html) too, and [here](http://markun.cs.shinshu-u.ac.jp/mirror/mizar/JFM/Axiomatics/tarski.html) in the "Content" link provided as a pdf.

What I want to understand is how the theory contains sets at all, and then where which kinds of sets resides.

The first question would be answered if we establish why the theory contains the empty set. I read the theads

[The existence of the empty set is an axiom of ZFC or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not)

and

[How do I get the existence of a set in ZFC following Jech?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132392/how-do-i-get-the-existence-of-a-set-in-zfc-following-jech)

However they are concerned with a pretty different set theory.

Now if the empty set would be established, then I guess the theory guarantees the existence of a [Grothendieck universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) with lots of nice stuff. Okay there is the claim on the Wikipedia page that the Tarski axiom implies the [axiom of infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) and the existence of any set would mean we win. However I can not see how that Tarski axiom formulation

```
 reserve x,y,z,u,N,M,X,Y,Z for set;
 ...
 ex M st N in M &
 (for X,Y holds X in M & Y c= X implies Y in M) &
 (for X st X in M ex Z st Z in M & for Y st Y c= X holds Y in Z) &
 (for X holds X c= M implies X,M are_equipotent or X in M);
```

lets us generate even one axiom if the all-quantor goes over an empty domain.

Another path: If we search for the first occurence of the empty set in the Mizar Mathematical Library, then we find it [here](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/xboole_0.html#RC1) right after the axiom schema of separation is established. Clicking on "proof" then allows us to see how the schema is used to show the existence. It so happens that in the end of the following article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set

they exactly refer to a procedure to get a set from the separation axiom, however I read this and it still doesn't clear things up. And it goes without saying that there is no "it exists a set such..." axiom in the Mizar library.

Lastly, I can note that the defintion or specification of the empty set

```
 definition
 func {} -> set means
 :: XBOOLE_0:def 1
 not ex x being set st x in it;
```

is done by introducing something they denote "functor", but it's not a functor in the category theoretical sense, I think it's a term constructor as they also use this to define the pair in on the axiom page

```
  definition let y; func { y } means
  :: TARSKI:def 1
  x in it iff x = y;
  let z; func { y, z } means
```

I'm not even certain if this is an axiom guaranteeing the existence of the "functor" or if it's merely notation construction.

One more note: I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200652/what-is-the-tarskigrothendieck-set-theory-about) SE thread and in the answer the poster says "One often needs to check that some definition doesn't depend on which universe it's carried out in". I wonder, if I'm interested in sets for doing topology and propability theory, will this named disadvantage be really one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axiomatic set theories are usually supposed to use *classical first-order logic* as their substratum, and classical first-order logic as it is usually formalized *implicitly* requires that the domain of discourse must be non-empty.

More technically, if $\varphi$ is any logical formula in the language we're considering, then first-order logic proves $\exists x(\varphi \lor \neg \varphi)$ using purely *logical* axioms and rules, needing no set-theoretical axioms at all for this. Therefore the existence of *some* set doesn't need to be made an axiom of the theory -- it can be assumed as a boundary condition because the theory is a creature of first-order logic.

It is possible to formulate a variant of first-order logic that *doesn't* prove things that are false in the empty domain of discourse -- but the cost of this is more complex rules for reasoning about quantifiers, and the only thing it buys us is to allow a rather uninteresting corner case as a model, which isn't usually considered worth the price.

Certainly it would be pointless to make logic itself more complex only to need to add an explicit axiom to our set theory whose effect is to *negate* what we just did.

---

This is often felt to be a rather subtle point, though, so to avoid confusion some introductions may choose to include "something exists" as an explicit axiom anyway -- after all this doesn't hurt unless we put a special value on having a *minimal* set of axioms, which is generally not achievable when there are axiom schemas around anyway.

Also, in set theories such as ZF where there is already, for other reasons, one or more axioms with a $\exists$ as the outermost quantifier, then it can be seen as worth a modest amount of ink to point out that this would allow us to prove that a set exists, *even if* we chose to work in a logic background that doesn't do this itself.

Comment: If this "logic-set" is there but completeley unspecifyable to me, how can I properly work with it? This set isn't the empty set right? Also, if I view this set as the one generating the first Grothendieck universe via the Tarski axiom, then does this mean I have strange things in my universe?

Comment: @NickKidman: Typically, once you know that some set $A$ exists, you'd be able to manufacture the empty set from it by a separation axiom: $\{x\in A\mid (x\in x)\land (x\notin x)\}$ exists and is empty. However, the Wikipedia article you link to doesn't seem to include an axiom of separation. It is possible that the article assumes a variation of Replacement that subsumes Separation, by allowing the use of _partial_ functionals.

Comment: The list of axioms at the Wikipedia article seems particularly vague to me, there is no way to tell from that exposition what the axioms are able to prove.

Comment: Well, I say in my initial post that the library includes the axiom schema of separation. I also posted the link to the axioms of the prover, they include replacement, I think. as "scheme Fraenkel".

Comment: @Nick: Yes, the `scheme Fraenkel` does subsume Separation; it will produce the empty set if `P[x,y]` is chosen to be a contradiction.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I don't understand how I can write down the existence using the axiom of separation witout having any set at hand before. There is the substring "$\in X$" with quantified $X$ in it, but I have no X to start with. I've nothing to seperate something from. (I think I don't even know a priori that the empty set is a subset of any set, might not matter anyhow.) I also just read [this mathoverflow post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104464/tarski-grothendieck-set-theory-the-axiom-of-pairing-and-the-axiom-of-specificati) and they argue about the emptry set too.

Comment: @NickKidman: Of course you need to have some set at hand before you can use separation. The point of my comment was that _after_ first-order-logic proves that something exists (and that something must implicit be a set because everything the theory speaks about are sets), you can use Separation to get from there to the empty set.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I got it formally [here on their wiki](http://wiki.mizar.org/twiki/bin/view/Mizar/Tarski-GrothendieckSetTheory#SetAxiom). The underlying Mizar language is typed and they implicitly demand their types to be non-empty. Also, the "pairing axiom" and the other two after that in the articles are not the actual axioms, but consequences with which they start to work with and that's why they state them as definitions.

Comment: Just an addition regarding setting up the theory of first-order theories so as to allow empty universes of discourse: This extension gets interesting, an indeed crucial, as soon as we're interested in models which are not made of sets, but models in different categories. For instance, in most toposes, the statement "every set is empty or inhabited" is not true. Hence, by restricting to the classical definitions, we exclude much more than just the empty model. We also exclude all those which are not empty, but are not inhabited. Classically, this cannot happen, but in most toposes, it does.